# How fetch data in React without max length array limit?

Tags: reactjs, axios, drupal-8, json-api

I'm using axios to fetch data from headless Drupal 8 to my React component via the JSONAPI Drupal module.
When I make exactly the same fetch request through Postman (URL and headers are the same), I get and array of 300+ objects, but when fetching from React, the response is limited to 50 objects.
What limits my array length and how to override the limit to get the full array?
This request is placed in componentDidMount() in App.js of my React project, created by Create-React-App:

```
axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `${prodURL}/jsonapi/node/puzzle/?fields[node--puzzle]=field_filestack_handle,created&filter[eventfilter][condition][path]=field_event_reference.field_event_access_code&filter[eventfilter][condition][value]=${eventAccessCode}&sort=-created`,

            auth: {
                username: `${fetchUsername}`,
                password: `${fetchPassword}`
            },
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    data: response.data.data,
                    isLoading: false
                })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

Comment: Show some code man

Comment: Please show your postman request details and the code that makes the fetch call. If you have access to the server, then its easy to debug there by checking what you receive.

Comment: Just added my code. As I've mentioned, it is the same request I use in Postman, but in React it limits array length to 50.

Comment: Please show us how you query it using postman, is it the same url? are the values for your parameters the same? what if you hardcode the url in axios to test that everything is working correctly? As far as I know Axios doesn't filter results (I've always used it and I always have to filter in the backend) so my thought here is that there must be some parameter that is filtering your result in that url.

Comment: I can't expose auth data publicly but if you use this URL in Postman without auth header, you'll get the array of the same number of objects (the hidden values are not relevant since we are talking about max array length).
http://partypics.gallery/jsonapi/node/puzzle/?fields%5bnode--puzzle%5d=field_filestack_handle,created&filter%5bevent-filter%5d%5bcondition%5d%5bpath%5d=field_event_reference.field_event_access_code&filter%5bevent-filter%5d%5bcondition%5d%5bvalue%5d=123456&sort=-created

Comment: Just noticed that the response is limited to 50 even if I'm opening the URL directly in the browser. But as you can see yourself, Postman gives the full array somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON API Drupal module limited the response. I should have used [Pagination](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/json-api/pagination)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash chunk to split the array into an array of arrays that have the length of 50.

```
_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
// => [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```